# Get "Adj Close" using pandas DataReader

Tags: python, pandas, datareader, yahoo-finance

I just switched from pandas.io to pandas_datareader and I'm having difficulties pulling in just Adjusted Close prices. before I could use the following code

```
pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)['Adj Close']
```

now when I try the datareader (imported as web) it does not work.

```
web.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)['Adj Close']
```

I've tried to find documentation to see if there is a new argument that the pandas_datareader uses, but I have had no luck. Is there anyway to pull in just Adjusted Close data using the new pandas library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i would use [DataReader](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html) for that:

```
In [61]: from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

In [62]: DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', '2016-06-25', '2016-06-30')['Adj Close']
Out[62]:
Date
2016-06-27    92.040001
2016-06-28    93.589996
2016-06-29    94.400002
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

actually your code works as well (pandas 0.18.1 and pandas_datareader 0.2.1):

```
In [63]: import pandas_datareader.data as web

In [64]: web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', '2016-06-25', '2016-06-30')
Out[64]:
                 Open       High        Low      Close    Volume  Adj Close
Date
2016-06-27  93.000000  93.050003  91.500000  92.040001  45489600  92.040001
2016-06-28  92.900002  93.660004  92.139999  93.589996  39311500  93.589996
2016-06-29  93.970001  94.550003  93.629997  94.400002  36427800  94.400002

In [65]: web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', '2016-06-25', '2016-06-30')['Adj Close']
Out[65]:
Date
2016-06-27    92.040001
2016-06-28    93.589996
2016-06-29    94.400002
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @Evy555, what versions of pandas and pandas_datareader do you have? Andwhat error / exception do you receive?

Comment: I went ahead and rewrote everything using the exact same code. Not sure why, but it now works for both DataReader and get_data_yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is no longer viable. When I run:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL')
```

This yields:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ichart.finance.yahoo.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /table.csv?a=0&ignore=.csv&s=AAPL&b=1&e=7&d=6&g=d&f=2017&c=2010 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

Looks like Quanld could provide a better [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44138480/6695757)

Comment: Yeah Yahoo has had some issues recently. I switched to google.

Comment: @Evy555 have you found a solution for getting adjusted close data?
 (concerned about dividends) I don't believe google's close field is adjusted.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google still doesn't adjust prices for dividends. I haven't found another source that does.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from Yahoo is broken. Use Google instead, if you can. For example:

```
df = web.DataReader("AAPL", 'google', start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

from pandas_datareader import get_data_yahoo as gy

```
X = gy('AAPL','2019-01-01','2019-03-15')['Adj Close']

print(X.head())
```