# Yahoo Finance API / URL not working: Python fix for Pandas DataReader

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

Yahoo Finance URL has not been accessible using the Pandas DataReader's "yahoo" method since 16 May 2017. I have yet to test this fix-yahoo-finance: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance that was posted just yesterday, with the statement: "Yahoo! finance has decommissioned their historical data API".

EDIT August 2, 2017: I have since followed the steps in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance to: $ pip3 install fix_yahoo_finance --upgrade --no-cache-dir, upgraded pandas_datareader to work with "fix-yahoo-finance 0.0.6", and amended codes:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start='2017-04-23', end='2017-05-24')
```

Note that the order of the last 2 data columns are 'Adj Close' and 'Volume' ie. not the previous format. For my purpose, they are simply reset to the original format:

```
cols = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']
data.reindex(columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the steps in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance to: $ pip3 install fix_yahoo_finance --upgrade --no-cache-dir and also upgraded pandas_datareader to be sure.

The "fix-yahoo-finance 0.0.6" worked well, for example BHP.AX:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo('BHP.AX', start='2017-04-23', end='2017-05-24')
```

Note that the order of the last 2 data columns are 'Adj Close' and 'Volume' ie. not the previous format. For my purpose, they are reset to the original format:

```
cols = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']
data.reindex(columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using Quandl. I'm not sure if Yahoo is going to be reliable after their acquisition. 
In Quandl if you have multiple symbols you have to loop. Read the [docs](https://docs.quandl.com/docs/installation-1) and do something like this:

```
    import quandl as qdl
    start_date = '2016-01-01'
    end_date = '2017-05-22'
    for symbol in symbols:

        quandldata = qdl.get_table("WIKI/PRICES",qopts={"columns":["date", "adj_close"]},
        ticker=symbol, date = {'gte': start_date,'lte' : end_date})
        # specify that the quandldata df has index col = 'date'
        quandldata = quandldata.set_index(["date"], drop=True)
        # rename col adj close to the respective symbol to prevent clash w/ same name for all cols
        quandldata = quandldata.rename(columns={'adj_close': symbol})
        df = df.join(quandldata)
```

Comment: Thanks and I'm not sure if Quandl provides data for ASX stocks. One data vendor eoddata.com may be worth a look.

Comment: I can only grab 20 stocks with a time limit for every 10 minutes. If it exceeds more than 20 stocks within the 10 minute time limit, an error will pop up, breaking the code. So if I wanted to grab all 505 stocks from the S&P 500, it would take me a min of 4.2 hours (((505 stock/20 stocks)*10 minutes)/60 minutes). That's very inefficient. If you try to grab stock data for MSFT using pandas_datareader with yahoo, and click on the link that you get from the error saying "YAHOO! Will be right back." `https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&a=0&b=1&c=2016&d=0&e=1&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv`

Comment: With Quandl, you'd want to open a free account. When you do, you'll get 2000calls/10min.

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdweb
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance # must pip install first 
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo('SPY','2017-05-20','2017-05-23')
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(['SPY','QQQ'],'2017-05-01','2017-05-23', as_panel=False,group_by = 'ticker')
```

Answer (score 2):

A way around:

```
pip install yfinance
```

Code to get the 'AAPL' dataset:

```
import yfinance as yf
btc = yf.download('AAPL', start=datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1), end=datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 2))
print(btc.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

I like user3443068 answer as it's simple.

I also would suggest looking at using Google as your source as the yahoo instance is probably going to go through many deprecated versions given where the company's going.

```
def get_ret(tickers_ls, start_dt, end_dt):
        #create dataframe
        df_ret=pd.DataFrame() 

        #get prices for all tickers 
        for tk in tickers:
            p = wb.DataReader(tk, "google", start_date, end_date).Close
            df_ret_tmp = p.to_frame()['Close'].reset_index()
            df_ret_tmp['Ticker']=tk
        ## append
            df_ret=df_ret.append(df_ret_tmp) 

        #pivot and get into single dataframe
        pivoted = df_ret.pivot(index='Date', columns='Ticker')
        pivoted.columns = pivoted.columns.droplevel(0)

        return pivoted
```

Comment: Google is not really a viable option because they adjust prices for splits, but not for dividends