# Cannot scrape crumb from yahoo finance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am trying to scrape the historical data from Yahoo finance stocks. I found some code from the internet and modified it. It worked at first, but now I cannot scrape the crumb from yahoo. Can anyone advise how to fix this?

The first time I scraped yahoo, it scraped 20 sets of data and stopped working. I started it again and it did't work

The relevant code is attached below

```
def _get_crumbs_and_cookies(stock):
    """
    get crumb and cookies for historical data csv download from yahoo finance

    parameters: stock - short-handle identifier of the company 

    returns a tuple of header, crumb and cookie
    """

    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/history'.format(stock)
    with requests.session():
        header = {'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                   'Expires': '-1',
                   'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) \
                   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
                   Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'
                   }

        website = requests.get(url, headers=header)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(website.text, 'lxml')
        crumb = re.findall('"CrumbStore":{"crumb":"(.+?)"}', str(soup))

    return (header, crumb[0], website.cookies)
```

And the entire original code can be found at:
https://maikros.github.io/yahoo-finance-python/

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like Yahoo Finance may have blocked you, or you made a change which broke the scraping. Try again later and see if it works then (blocking is often temporary).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at this post here: [Yahoo Finance API / URL not working: Python fix for Pandas DataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112403/yahoo-finance-api-url-not-working-python-fix-for-pandas-datareader)

It looks like yahoo finance has discontinued their historical data :(

You can try google ! However, Google is not really a viable option because they adjust prices for splits, but not for dividends.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking for a finance API like a week ago. 
I figured, that either Yahoo or Google should supply a good one, but I had to find out, that both have been discontinued.

For now I'm using [WorldTradingData](https://www.worldtradingdata.com/) which is free for 250 requests a day. I don't know which scale you will be working on, but if you need this for an App they do also offer paid subscriptions with way more requests possible.
I found their customer support to be very nice and helpful, as I found out that some live quotes were wrong and they only a day later already switched the location they get their data from and everything was great again!

I hope this gets you where you want to be!